# InputBox value as the value_if_error for IFERROR INDEX/MATCH

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to use the InputBox result as the condition if the INDEX/MATCH doesn't return a value. Will be a four character string.

All results I found are for numbers or ranges. None were passing values as the error condition.

I feel like I'm 90% of the way there because **inpMfrDiv** displays the user input in the formula bar when I run the macro, but in the worksheet it displays #NAME? ERROR. **inpMfrCode** doesn't work at all and just puts the formula in the cells.

Here is a condensed version of the macro.

```vb
Sub PriceFileThings5()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim rngDynamicO, rngDynamicP, rngDynamicQ, rngDynamicR, rngDynamicS, rngDynamicT As Range
    Dim inpMfrCode As String
    Dim inpMfrDiv As String
    
    lastRow = Sheets("Contract").Range("N1").End(xlDown).Row
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set rngDynamicS = wb.Sheets("Contract").Range("S2:S" & lastRow)
    Set rngDynamicT = wb.Sheets("Contract").Range("T2:T" & lastRow)
           
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Call OptimizeCode_Begin
                              
    wb.Names.Add Name:="rngReturnR", _
      RefersTo:="=ItemMaster_Matches!$D$2:INDEX(ItemMaster_Matches!$D:$D, COUNTA(ItemMaster_Matches!$D:$D))"
    wb.Names.Add Name:="rngReturnS", _
      RefersTo:="=ItemMaster_Matches!$E$2:INDEX(ItemMaster_Matches!$E:$E, COUNTA(ItemMaster_Matches!$E:$E))"
    wb.Names.Add Name:="rngReturnT", _
      RefersTo:="=ItemMaster_Matches!$F$2:INDEX(ItemMaster_Matches!$F:$F, COUNTA(ItemMaster_Matches!$F:$F))"
                
    'NEED USER INPUT BOX FOR THESE RANGES
    '*************************
                
    With rngDynamicS
        inpMfrCode = InputBox("Please enter the 4 character Manufacturer Code")
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnS, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), " & inpMfrCode & ")"
        lastRow = Range("N1:N" & Range("N1").End(xlDown).Row).Rows.Count
        Range("S2" & ":S" & lastRow).FillDown
        'Application.Calculate
    End With
                
    With rngDynamicT
        inpMfrDiv = InputBox("Please enter the 4 character Manufacturer Division")
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnT, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), " & inpMfrDiv & ")"
        lastRow = Range("N1:N" & Range("N1").End(xlDown).Row).Rows.Count
        Range("T2" & ":T" & lastRow).FillDown
        'Application.Calculate
    End With
    '*************************

    ActiveSheet.Calculate
    Call OptimizeCode_End
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting the string `inpMfrCode` into the formula, without wrapping it in quotes.

That is to say, the formula it's creating looks like:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnS, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), ABCD)
```

When you actually want it to write:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnS, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), "ABCD")
```

Try swapping out your `.Formula` lines to:

```
.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnS, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), """ & inpMfrCode & """)"
```

and

```
.Formula = "=IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnT, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), """ & inpMfrDiv & """)"
```

Comment: of course it was something stupid...lol.  Thanks.  inpMfrDiv works perfectly.  Although for some reason inpMfrCode is still just inserting the formula.  Perhaps a format issue?

Comment: Shouldn't be formatting. You haven't hit CTRL-` have you? That would cause ALL formulas to appear though.

Comment: Oh well that's just strange, because they're both set up the same.  And nope formulas are not set to show.

Comment: The formula starts with `=` in both cases? And nothing before, like a `?

Comment: Just found the problem.  For some reason the formula isn't filling down correctly.  Its just displaying =IFERROR(INDEX(rngReturnS, MATCH(Contract!$A2, rngLookUp, FALSE)), "haha") all the way down the sheet.  

But even when I input the formula manually it still won't fill down correctly...and nope, no tick marks either.

Comment: I have no idea what the problem was but just retyped the formula manually into notepad++ and resaved it and now it works like a charm.  Thanks so much for you help!