# How to resolve #NAME? error in VBA when attempting to set a cell value using a variable in the function

Tags: excel, function, formula, quote, vba

I am building a simple macro named Update for a form control button in excel. When the button is pressed, I want a `vlookup` to execute in the button's sheet (named *"Checker"*), against the $B$7:$E$1048576 range in another sheet named *"All Account Log"* within the same workbook.

This vlookup formula should populate in rows 5-105 in column 5 ("E") of *Checker*, and for each respective row should take an input from column B to check against *All Account Log*'s range. Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub Update()

Dim Month As String
Dim i As Integer

Month = Cells(2, 2).Value

For i = 5 To 105
    Cells(i, 5).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ",'All Account Log'!$B$7:$E$1048576,4,0)," & Month & ")"

Next i

End Sub
```

If the vlookup is successful, the formula in each row of column E should pull back the respective column's data. If the vlookup does not find a match, the formula should copy the value from Cell(2,2), which is a string input by the user - a month's name. When I run the macro, the vlookup does what I want, however, when it does not find a match, the resulting formulae read "#NAME?". What can I do to fix this? I have a feeling there is some syntactical issue with how my formula references the Month variable (the value of Cell(2,2)), but I cannot figure out what the error is.

After running the macro and clicking on one of the cells with the #NAME? result, the formula in the formula bar reads:
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,'All Account Log'!$B$7:$E$1048576,4,0),Jan)

Here I have the input "Jan" as the Month name, so I expect the result to be "Jan" rather than "#NAME?" Your thoughts are appreciated!

Comment: FWIW, potential code improvements (1) `Cells(i, 5).Value` should be `Cells(i, 5).Formula` (but usually works anyway - Excel is fairly good at guessing that you want that value to be a formula) (2) Avoid using VBA function names (e.g. `Month`) as variable names (3) You can replace the `," & Month & ")"` part of your code with `,$B$2)"` (4) You can replace `Cells(i, 5).Value = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B" & i & ", ...` with `Cells(5, 5).Resize(101, 1).Formula = "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5, ...` and then you wouldn't need the loop - you would be assigning the formula to all 101 cells in a single statement.

Comment: LOL - I have just been cleaning up questions with the [macros] tag used incorrectly.  Corrected yours and looked at the question and commented on it.  [The next one I looked at](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48172567/6535336) was posted about 30 minutes before yours, but has the identical issue as yours - writing a string into a formula without quotes around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really want:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,'All Account Log'!$B$7:$E$1048576,4,0),"Jan")
```

instead of:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP($B5,'All Account Log'!$B$7:$E$1048576,4,0),Jan)
```

so use:

```
Month = """" & Cells(2, 2).Value & """"
```

in the VBA code.